# Populating Cassandra database using Python

Tags: python, mysql, database, cassandra

I am on Linux platform with Cassandra database. I want to insert Images data into Cassandra database using Python Code from a remote server. Previously, I had written a python code that inserts Images' data into MySQL database from a remote server. Please see the code below for MySQL

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb as mdb
import psycopg2
import sys
import MySQLdb
def read_image(i):   
    filename="/home/faban/Downloads/Python/Python-Mysql/images/im"
    filename=filename+str(i)+".jpg"
    print(filename)
    fin = open(filename)    
    img = fin.read()   
    return img
con = MySQLdb.connect("192.168.50.12","root","faban","experiments" )  
with con:
    print('connecting to database')
    range_from=input('Enter range from:')
    range_till=input('Enter range till:')
    for i in range(range_from,range_till):
     cur = con.cursor()
     data = read_image(i)
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO images VALUES(%s, %s)", (i,data, ))
     cur.close()
     con.commit()
con.close()
```

---

This code successfully inserts data into MySQL database which is located at .12
I want to modify the same code to insert data into Cassandra database which is also located at .12
Please help me out in this regard.

Comment: try python cassandra driver. There is blob support in cassandra. https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I create a simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.images (
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    data blob);
```

I can load those images with Python code that is similar to yours, but with some minor changes to use the DataStax Python Cassandra driver (`pip install cassandra-driver`):

```
#imports for DataStax Cassandra driver and sys
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.cluster import SimpleStatement
import sys

#reading my hostname, username, and password from the command line; defining my Cassandra keyspace as as variable.
hostname=sys.argv[1]
username=sys.argv[2]
password=sys.argv[3]
keyspace="stackoverflow"

#adding my hostname to an array, setting up auth, and connecting to Cassandra
nodes = []
nodes.append(hostname)
auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=username, password=password)
ssl_opts = {}
cluster = Cluster(nodes,auth_provider=auth_provider,ssl_options=ssl_opts)
session = cluster.connect(keyspace)

#setting my image name, loading the file, and reading the data
name = "IVoidWarranties.jpg"
fileHandle = open("/home/aploetz/Pictures/" + name)
imgData = fileHandle.read()

#preparing and executing my INSERT statement
strCQL = "INSERT INTO images (name,data) VALUES (?,?)"
pStatement = session.prepare(strCQL)
session.execute(pStatement,[name,imgData])

#closing my connection
session.shutdown()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aaron! sudo pip install --install-option="--no-cython" saved my day.

Comment: @MuhammadKaramShehzad good to hear it helped!  Don't forget to upvote and/or accept!